# Where Clause in Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, where-clause

How this `where` clause is working?

```
(digit, index) => digit.Length < index
```

**Code**

```
public void Linq5() 
    { 
        string[] digits = { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" }; 

        var shortDigits = digits.Where((digit, index) => digit.Length < index); 

        Console.WriteLine("Short digits:"); 
        foreach (var d in shortDigits) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("The word {0} is shorter than its value.", d); 
        } 
    }
```

[Source](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Restriction-Operators-b15d29ca#WhereIndexed)

**Edited for clarification** 
*As per Iswanto San*

```
(digit, index) => digit.Length < index
```

declaration of variable :

```
(digit, index) -- digit as array of digits
```

Condition (like `where` clause in `SQL`):

```
digit.Length < index
```

Correct if am I wrong?
if I am going right then what is the role of `=>`

Comment: It's just a lambda expression which gets executed per item, giving you the item and the index, and returning a `bool` (which serves as a discriminator for the `where` clause).

Comment: thanks for your quick reply, but not getting what exactly happenning in where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
(digit, index) => digit.Length < index
```

`digit` will refer to array content (in this case `digits`), the datatype is `String`.
`index` will refer to array index, the datatype is `int`.

So that condition will output the array content that has length less than it's index (position).

For example:

`digits="zero", index=0` => false, length=4, index=0

`digits="one", index=1` => false, length=3, index=1

`digits="two", index=2` => false, length=3, index=2

`digits="three", index=3` => false, length=5, index=3

`digits="four", index=4` => false, length=4, index=4

`digits="five", index=5` => true, length=4, index=5

More: [Enumerable.Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx)

Comment: `=>` refers the same as in C# or SQL?

Comment: `=>` is [lambda operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311046.aspx)

Comment: if I want to learn Linq than first I need to start with lambda ??

Comment: You can start learn using `Query Expression Syntax` which have SQL-like syntax, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399367.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This will return all elements from the list, which `Length` is lower then position in that list.

MSDN: [`Enumerable.Where<TSource> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Int32, Boolean>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx)

> The first argument of predicate represents the element to test. The second argument represents the zero-based index of the element within source.

It should return these elements:

```
{ "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" }
```

Answer (score 2):

It selects strings which length is smaller than it's index in the array.